# How to pass date value in sql stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to insert purchase date in table.

My table

```
purchaseDate date (data type)
```

C# code

```
string purchaseDate = "";
public string _PurchaseDate
{
    get { return purchaseDate; }
    set
    {
        DateTime purchaseDateF = DateTime.Parse(value.Trim());
        purchaseDate = purchaseDateF.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
    }
}
```

My stored Proc

```
@purchasedate,

insert into tbl_name (purchaseDate) values (@purchasedate)
```

If I pass purchaseDate = "29-may-14" its showing error on converting nvarchar into date.

Where did I make an error?

Thanks...

Comment: I believe your `purchaseDate` column type is `DATE` or something and you try to insert characters..

Comment: What is datatype of `purchaseDate` in your table?

Comment: You've shown a property (and an oddly named one at that, with an odd type - why isn't it just a `DateTime`?) - but no database code... Try to avoid string conversions wherever possible.

Comment: Do not try to convert the DateTime variable (the value) to a string. Pass it directly as a parameter to your stored procedure

Comment: purchaseDate is date datatype

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure? Are you using `SqlParameter`s?

Comment: yes i am using SqlParameter

Comment: The best format to use for dates (in queries and strings) is the ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS:MMM` to remove any ambiguity. You date `29-May-2014` would be `2014-05-29T00:00:00.000`. It has the benefit of being region agnostic too (i.e. handles UK/US/etc dates in same way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass it as a string. Pass it *as a date/time*. In fact, it is very unclear to me why `_PurchaseDate` is a `string` and not a `DateTime` in the first place. But however it is stored in your app: when you add it as a parameter, convert (parse) it to a `DateTime` **first**, and add the typed date. Not a `string`.

In an ideal world:

```
public DateTime PurchaseDate {get;set;}
//...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("purchasedate", obj.PurchaseDate);
```

Then nothing more is required.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting it in a certain format, insert as normal DateTime value and then when retreieving it, convert to formatted string...

Change your C# datatype from string to date:

```
    public DateTime _PurchaseDate{get;set;}
```

Do your insert with "_PurchaseDate", I am guessing you want to display it on a client app in a certain format, so then add property like this:

```
    public string _StrPurchaseDate
    {
        get
        {
            return ((DateTime)_PurchaseDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
```

now just retrieve the date as a string, unless you really need to store it as a certain format in sql

NOTE: If your database Date column contains NULLS, it will break when retrieving values from the database so change to nullable DateTime datatype and then check for nulls when converting:

```
    public DateTime? _PurchaseDate{get;set;}

    public string _StrPurchaseDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_PurchaseDate != null)
            {
                return ((DateTime)_PurchaseDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) inside your stored procedure to transform your `string` value to appropriate database type.